# Individual column filtering with multiselect dropdown in bootstrap datatable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am working on bootstrap datatable. I want to add filetr functionality like excel to individual column like this [Simlar example](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Excel-like-Bootstrap-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Plugin/)

But the problem is I am using bootstrap datatable. Here is my snippet [My Example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/srLzeh5a/10/)

Here is similar example [Similar Example](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/cumulative_filtering.html?_sm_au_=iVVJMr7Q7kSWZKrj#)

But instead of textbox I want multiselect dropdown. Basically I want to filter individual column like excel. Please help me.